# Can we rely on op== to binary-compare floating-point values?

Tags: c++, floating-point

We all know (right?!) that one should not compare floating-point values by testing for equality (`operator==`).

But what if I actually want to determine whether two `float`s `a` and `b` are *binary equal*? If they're not allowed to be NaN (or other "special values"), is this "safe"? Can I rely on `operator==` to function in this way?

Comment: What is your proposed use of this binary compare of floats? In other words, why do you want to do this? It's likely that there's a better way to accomplish your actual goal.

Comment: @Michael: My goal is to read the answers to this question, and in doing so expand my knowledge and understanding of all the tools of our profession.

Comment: @MichaelKohne Besides the OPs mentioned goal (which is a valid and often ignored one), there are many situations where a binary compare would be sufficient. You don't always need some fancy epsilon comparison, when you just want to check for a specific exact value and don't (or even shouldn't) care about approximately similar values due to rounding (therefore I also don't like the first sentence of the question too much).

Comment: @Christian: I guess I generalised a little.

Comment: Note that although there are many cases where using `==` with floats is not a good idea, there are also cases where it's perfectly reasonable; for instance, if you do `f = 0;`, a later test like `if (f == 0)` does exactly what it looks like; there's no imprecision or uncertainty.  So I think one should take the oft-heard maxim "never compare floats with ==" with a grain of salt... (and not repeat it blindly)

Comment: More realistically, `if (f != 0.0) g = 2.0/f; else ...` is a perfect test. However, `if (f != 0.3) g = 2.0/(f-0.3);` is _not_. FP is tricky.

Comment: @MSalters Really the case where this has cropped up for me in the past is the use of specific floating-point values (usually zero) as out-of-bound values for floating-point calculations.  This usage is quite handy and checking for such values with `==` is perfectly fine–and indeed the right thing to do–but nonetheless, one still gets chaff about it from people blindly applying the "no == with floats" guideline without actually thinking about what's going on...

Comment: @MichaelKohne: If one has a pure function f(x) that is expensive to compute, and it is likely that it will be called repeatedly with certain values, knowing that `q=f(x)` and `ExactEquivalent(x,y)` would allow one to skip the computation of f(y).  The `==` operator is defective in that regard, however, in that it reports 0 and (-1*0) as equivalent when they are not [at least not unless +Inf, -Inf, and Nan are also considered equivalent], and it regards NaN as not equivalent to itself, even though it obviously is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

(Assuming IEEE-754 representations) almost, but not quite.  If you can rule out NaNs, you still need to deal with the fact that `+0.0` and `-0.0` have different binary encodings, but compare equal (because both are *exactly zero*).

Of course, C++ doesn't require IEEE-754.  So strictly speaking, all bets are off.

If you want to check for (in)equality of encoding, just use `memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof a)`.

Comment: This fails to consider extended precision. See my answer.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: that would be addressed by using `memcmp` as I suggested.

Comment: Does `memcmp` force a float store? Is it guaranteed that the optimizer doesn't end up seeing the comparison of two values in registers and simply compare those values? I would hope, that given it has a size argument, the answer is yes, but I wouldn't write a critical piece of software without testing that assumption. Perhaps it compares something unrounded.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Yes, the "as-if" rule in the standard forces the behavior to be indistinguishable from what would occur if both values were stored, because a value needs to be stored in order to pass its address to a function.  (They need not actually be stored; they could, for instance, be rounded to their actual precision and then copied into general-purpose registers and compared there as integer encodings).

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer ignores a very important aspect: extended precision floating point. The CPU may be doing calculations with a bit-size that exceeds your storage size. This will particularly be true if you use `float` but can also be true of `double` and other floating point types.

To show the problem, the following **assert may actually fail** depending on how the compilation was done and how the chip behaves.

```
  void function( float a )
  {
     float b = a / 0.12345;
     assert( b == (a/0.12345) );
  }
```

Now, in this reduced example it will likely always pass, but there are many cases where it will not. Simply look at [GCC Bug 323](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323) and look at how many defects are marked as duplicates. This extended precision causes problems for many people, and it may also cause problems for you.

If you need a guarantee what you'll need to do is make a comparison function that takes two float parameters and guarantee that the function is never inlined (stored floats are not subject to extended precision). That is, you must ensure those floats are actually stored. There is also a GCC option called `-ffloat-store` I believe which forces storage, perhaps it can be used here on your individual function.

Comment: Does this really answer the question? If `a` and `b` don't even have the same amount of bits (due to extended floating point precision), then the question whether they're binary identical is a bit meaningless.

Comment: The option you refer to is `-ffloat-store`.

Comment: @MSalters, the question asks can he rely on operator==, so my answer would be a __No__.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y No, the question asks "can we rely on `operator==` to function in this way`?, where "this way" is binary equality. So MSalters has a point, though I'm not sure if this really invalidates your answer.

Comment: @ChristianRau, I just shortened in my comment, but I understood he meant binary equality. MSalters is correct that the notion of binary equality doesn't make sense, thus my answer implies that using `==` this way is wrong. That is, it won't work.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: If `x==y` doesn't guarantee that `x` and `y` are coerced to their specified types, does a result of 0 mean *anything*?  In many cases, I don't think it's helpful for compilers to spend time rounding things to lower precision, but comparisons only make sense between things of the same, known, type [btw, if I were designing a language, I would require that floating-point comparisons only be performed between operands of the same type]. Incidentally, I've often thought it would be helpful for compilers to have types for "strict" and "expansive" versions of `float` and `double`

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: ...where e.g. a `strict float` would disable all implicit conversions except to the expansive types, while expansive floats would use extended precision for intermediate results in cases where it would either be faster or could improve precision, *but* expansive floats would guarantee that if something is stored to a variable which is read multiple times, all reads would see the *same* value. If rounding is never required, the compiler wouldn't have to round it, but if it's ever needed the compiler would have to do it *before the first use*. Know any languages like that?

Comment: Example for the last point: Given `auto float a=100001.0*12345.0; auto float b=a-1234500000; ... auto float c=a-1234500000; a=0;`, I would posit that a compiler should be allowed to set both `b` and `c` to 12345.0f (as though `a` held the exact result), or set both to 12384.0f (as though `a` held a result rounded to single precision), but *not* allowed to set them to different values. Would that make sense?